# Einstein Bot conditions

Tags: service-cloud-console, experience-cloud, einstein-bots

I am new to the Salesforce Einstein bot.
I have a requirement, a client doesn't want to show **connect with an Agent** option to the guest user on experience site while the authenticated users should be able to connect to the agent via **Einstein Chatbot**.

I want to know is there any work around, how can we achieve this?
Please help!
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did create multiple decision trees and didn't add the connect to an agent option in that menu where I didn't want to add. Hence, I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My org owners don't want live chat, so when it's chosen the bot automatically responds with "Oh sorry, no one is available. What would you like to do now?". It's not ideal, but it does the job and the user moves on to something suitable at that point.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).